# Create 2nd column with the result set of existing column shifting up a row

Tags: sql

I would like to generate a column called PY Pacing Revenue, where the values from Pacing Revenue are shifted a year up.

This Pacing Revenue can be referred to as the amount of revenue generated at this point last year. i.e. for the Year 2021, gross revenue up until 19/01/2021.

Below you can find the CASE statement that I am using to get the pacing flag. This is then used in another CASE statement to return paced gross revenue

```
SELECT SUM(z.paced_cy_gross)
  FROM (   SELECT CASE
                       WHEN y.include_in_cy_pacing = 'Y' THEN y.[gross_revenue]
                       ELSE 0 END AS paced_cy_gross
             FROM (   SELECT x.gross_revenue, x.include_in_cy_pacing
                        FROM (   SELECT      a.gross_revenue,
                                             CASE
                                                  WHEN c.booking_date <= CAST(CONCAT(
                                                                                  CAST(d.Year AS CHAR(4)),
                                                                                  '-',
                                                                                  CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS CHAR(2)),
                                                                                  '-',
                                                                                  CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS CHAR(2))) AS DATETIME) THEN
                                                      'Y'
                                                  ELSE 'N' END AS include_in_cy_pacing
                                   FROM      dbo.date AS d
                                   JOIN      dbo.factdaily AS a WITH (NOLOCK)
                                     ON d.ID = a.date_id
                                   LEFT JOIN dbo.contract AS c WITH (NOLOCK)
                                     ON c.ID = a.contract_id) x ) y ) z
 GROUP BY z.Year
 ORDER BY z.Year;
```

| Year | Pacing Revenue | PY Pacing Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 20000 | 25000 |
| 2021 | 25000 | 18000 |
| 2020 | 18000 | 22000 |
| 2019 | 22000 | [2018 pacing value] |

PY Pacing Revenue is my desire field.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `LAG` window function if your DBMS support it.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *,LAG( [Pacing Revenue] ) OVER(ORDER BY [YEAR])
FROM T 
ORDER BY  [Year] DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ec721/1/0)**:

```
| Year | Pacing Revenue |        |
|------|----------------|--------|
| 2022 |          20000 |  25000 |
| 2021 |          25000 |  18000 |
| 2020 |          18000 |  22000 |
| 2019 |          22000 |  11000 |
| 2018 |          11000 | (null) |
```

Comment: It works. I was hoping if this would be possible via a separate case statement to calculate the py pacing revenue.

Comment: Can I do this on my SSAS cube? Not sure what the calculated expression would look like. [Measures].[Paced Gross Revenue]
[In Charge Date].[In Charge Year].LAG(1)

Comment: I am not sure what's your expectation but you can refer `LAG` document  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15